# Python 3 code to generate simple crossword puzzles from a list of words/anagrams

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code takes a list of words that all (pairwise) share at least one letter, e.g.

```
words = ["forget", "fret", "for", "tort", "forge", "fore", "frog", "fort", "forte", "ogre"]
```

and creates what I'm calling a "sparse crossword" puzzle that looks like this.

```
-------FORT
----------O
------F-FOR
----FROGR-T
----F-R-E--
--OFORGET--
--G-R-E----
FORTE------
--E--------
```

I'd greatly appreciate any feedback on either the algorithm for inserting words into the puzzle (which results is a pretty "formulaic" grid) and the general structure/style of the Python code as well.

```
import enum
import itertools
import math
import numpy as np
import random


@enum.unique
class Direction(enum.Enum):
    ACROSS = enum.auto()
    DOWN = enum.auto()

    def __str__(self):
        return("ACROSS" if self is Direction.ACROSS else "DOWN")

    def get_deltas(self):
        delta_r = int(self == Direction.DOWN)
        delta_c = int(self == Direction.ACROSS)
        return(delta_r, delta_c)

    @staticmethod
    def random():
        return random.choice(list(Direction))


class GridWord:
    def __init__(self, word: str, r: int, c: int, direction: Direction):
        if not isinstance(word, str):
            raise TypeError("word must be a string")
        if not (isinstance(r, int) and isinstance(c, int) and r >= 0 and c >= 0):
            raise ValueError("Row and column positions must be positive integers")
        if not isinstance(direction, Direction):
            raise TypeError("Direction must be an enum of type Direction")

        self.word = word.upper()
        self.r1 = r
        self.c1 = c
        self.direction = direction
        self.delta_r, self.delta_c = self.direction.get_deltas()

        self.__len = len(self.word)
        self.r2 = self.r1 + (self.__len - 1)* self.delta_r
        self.c2 = self.c1 + (self.__len - 1)* self.delta_c

    def __str__(self):
        return(f"{self.word}, ({self.r1}, {self.c1}) -- ({self.r2}, {self.c2}), {self.direction}")

    def __len__(self):
        return(self.__len)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, str):
            # The left operand is a string
            return(item in self.word)
        elif isinstance(item, tuple) and len(item) == 2 and isinstance(item[0], int) and isinstance(item[1], int):
            # The left operand is a tuple that contains two integers, i.e. a 
            # coordinate pair
            return(self.r1 <= item[0] and item[0] <= self.r2 and
                   self.c1 <= item[1] and item[1] <= self.c2)
        else:
            raise TypeError("'in <GridWord>' requires string or coordinate pair as left operand")

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return(self.word[item])
        except: 
            raise

    def intersects(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, GridWord):
            raise TypeError("Intersection is only defined for two GridWords")
        if self.direction == other.direction:
            raise ValueError("Intersection is only defined for GridWords placed in different directions")

        for idx1, letter1 in enumerate(self.word):
            for idx2, letter2 in enumerate(other.word):
                rr1 = self.r1 + idx1*self.delta_r
                cc1 = self.c1 + idx1*self.delta_c
                rr2 = other.r1 + idx2*self.delta_c # because the direction is reversed
                cc2 = other.c1 + idx2*self.delta_r
                if letter1 == letter2 and rr1 == rr2 and cc1 == cc2:
                    return(True)
        return(False)

    def overlaps(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, GridWord):
            raise TypeError("Overlap check is only defined for two GridWords")
        if self.direction == other.direction:
            return((self.r1, self.c1) in other or (other.r1, other.c1) in self)

        for idx, letter in enumerate(self.word):
            rr = self.r1 + idx*self.delta_r
            cc = self.c1 + idx*self.delta_c
            if (rr, cc) in other:
                return(True)
        return(False)


    def adjacent_to(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, GridWord):
            raise TypeError("Adjacency is only defined for two GridWords")
        if self.direction != other.direction:
            return(False)
        for delta in [-1, 1]:
            for idx in range(self.__len):
                r = self.r1 + idx*self.delta_r + delta*self.delta_c
                c = self.c1 + idx*self.delta_c + delta*self.delta_r
                if (r, c) in other:
                    return(True)

            # (-1) point directly to the left of (or above) a word placed across
            # (or down)
            #
            # (1) point directly to the right of (or below) a word placed across
            # (or down)
            if delta == -1:
                r = self.r1 + delta * self.delta_r
                c = self.c1 + delta * self.delta_c
            elif delta == 1:
                r = self.r2 + delta * self.delta_r
                c = self.c2 + delta * self.delta_c
            if (r, c) in other:
                return(True)
        return(False) 



class Grid:
    def __init__(self, num_rows = 50, num_cols = 50):
        self.num_rows = num_rows
        self.num_cols = num_cols
        self.grid = np.full([self.num_rows, self.num_cols], "")
        self.grid_words = []

    def __str__(self):
        s = ""


        for i in range(self.num_rows):
            for j in range(self.num_cols):
                s += self.grid[i][j] if self.grid[i][j] != "" else "-"
            s += "\n"
        return(s)

    def __approximate_center(self):
        center = (math.floor(self.num_rows / 2), math.floor(self.num_cols / 2))
        return(center)

    def __insert_word(self, grid_word):
        if not isinstance(grid_word, GridWord):
            raise TypeError("Only GridWords can be inserted into the Grid")
        delta_r, delta_c = grid_word.direction.get_deltas()
        for idx, letter in enumerate(grid_word.word):
            self.grid[grid_word.r1 + idx*delta_r, grid_word.c1 + idx*delta_c] = letter
        self.grid_words.append(grid_word)

    def __word_fits(self, word: str, r: int, c: int, d: Direction):
        # Make sure we aren't inserting the word outside the grid
        if ((d == Direction.DOWN and r + len(word) >= self.num_rows) or
            (d == Direction.ACROSS and c + len(word) >= self.num_cols)):
            return(False)
        grid_word = GridWord(word, r, c, d)


        check = False
        for gw in self.grid_words:
            if grid_word.adjacent_to(gw):
                # If the word is adjacent to any other words in the grid, we can
                # exit right away because it doesn't fit
                return(False)
            if grid_word.overlaps(gw):
                if d == gw.direction:
                    # If the word overlaps another word that is placed in the
                    # same direction, we can exit right away
                    return(False)
                elif not grid_word.intersects(gw):
                    # If the word overlaps another word that is placed in the 
                    # other direction but DOESN'T intersect it (i.e. the overlap
                    # doesn't happen on the same letter in each word), we can
                    # exit right away
                    return(False)
                else:
                    check = True
            else:
                # If the word doesn't overlap the current word (already in the
                # grid) that's being checked, we don't know yet whether or not
                # we CAN or CANNOT place it on the grid
                pass
        return(check)      




    def __scan_and_insert_word(self, word):
        if not isinstance(word, str):
            raise TypeError("Only strings can be inserted into the puzzle by scanning")
        if len(self.grid_words) == 0:
            self.__insert_word(GridWord(word, *self.__approximate_center(), Direction.random()))
            return(None)
        for d, r, c in itertools.product(list(Direction), range(self.num_rows), range(self.num_cols)):
            if self.__word_fits(word, r, c, d):
                grid_word = GridWord(word, r, c, d)
                self.__insert_word(grid_word)
                break

    def scan_and_insert_all_words(self, words):
        for word in words:
            self.__scan_and_insert_word(word)


    def __randomly_insert_word(self, word):
        if not isinstance(word, str):
            raise TypeError("Only strings can be randomly inserted into the puzzle")
        if len(self.grid_words) == 0:
            self.__insert_word(GridWord(word, *self.__approximate_center(), Direction.random()))
            return(None)
        num_iterations = 0
        while num_iterations <= 10000:
            rand_r = random.randint(0, self.num_rows - 1)
            rand_c = random.randint(0, self.num_cols - 1)
            d = Direction.random()
            if self.__word_fits(word, rand_r, rand_c, d):
                grid_word = GridWord(word, rand_r, rand_c, d)
                self.__insert_word(grid_word)
                break
            num_iterations += 1


    def crop(self):
        min_c = min([word.c1 for word in self.grid_words])
        min_r = min([word.r1 for word in self.grid_words])
        max_c = max([word.c2 for word in self.grid_words])
        max_r = max([word.r2 for word in self.grid_words])

        cropped_grid = Grid(max_r - min_r + 1, max_c - min_c + 1)
        for grid_word in self.grid_words:
            cropped_word = GridWord(grid_word.word, grid_word.r1 - min_r,
                                          grid_word.c1 - min_c, grid_word.direction)
            cropped_grid.__insert_word(cropped_word)
        return(cropped_grid)




random.seed(1)
words = ["forget", "fret", "for", "tort", "forge", "fore", "frog", "fort", "forte", "ogre"]
g = Grid()
g.scan_and_insert_all_words(words)
print(g.crop())
```

Comment: How are _FFORE_ or _FROGR_ words?

Comment: @Reinderien That is ... a bug I thought I fixed, but obviously didn't (and didn't notice here). That's embarrassing.

Comment: It's okay  it won't prevent you from having a meaningful review, with the caveat that CR feed back won't be expected to fix the bug if that's what you need help with. Such help comes from StackOverflow.

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks. No, that wasn't what I needed help with (since I didn't even notice it when I copied the grid into the question...) and I'm working on fixing it offline as we speak.

Comment: If you manage to fix it before an answer is posted here, you're still free to edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Validation

This:

```
words = ["forget", "fret", "for", "tort", "forge", "fore", "frog", "fort", "forte", "ogre"]
```

should probably receive some kind of validation to confirm that each word shares at least one letter. One simple way to do this is a `set`: iterate through each word, adding each letter of the word to the set. Then do a second iteration to ensure that the set intersects with each word.

### Enum name

```
def __str__(self):
    return("ACROSS" if self is Direction.ACROSS else "DOWN")
```

is not necessary. You should be able to simply do:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

### Implicit tuple

This:

```
    return(delta_r, delta_c)
```

does not require parens, nor does this:

```
                return(True)
```

### Dunders

```
    self.__len = len(self.word)
```

Don't name this variable with two underscores - that usually has a special meaning. (The same applies to `__word_fits`.) Even so, you don't need this variable at all - just use `len(self.word)` in your `__len__` method.

### Combined comparison

```
self.r1 <= item[0] and item[0] <= self.r2 and
self.c1 <= item[1] and item[1] <= self.c2
```

becomes

```
self.r1 <= item[0] <= self.r2 and
self.c1 <= item[1] <= self.c2
```

### Don't no-op `except`

Delete this try block, since it does nothing:

```
    try:
        return(self.word[item])
    except: 
        raise
```

### Coordinate nomenclature

`rr1` and `cc1` and their ilk are probably better expressed as `yy1` and `xx1`, etc.

### Overlap detection

You have some long loops to detect spatial overlap. Instead, consider building up an index structure that is composed of nested lists. Indexing `[y][x]` into the list can get you an inner structure that contains all words at that location, and for each of them, the offset into the word. This will be fairly cheap memory-wise and will greatly improve your runtime. It will also make `__word_fits` much nicer.

### Or semantics

```
            s += self.grid[i][j] if self.grid[i][j] != "" else "-"
```

can become

```
s += self.grid[i][j] or '-'
```

### Grid.**str**

Much ink has been spilled on the evils of successive immutable string concatenation. This is what `StringIO` is built for, so do that instead.

Or, if you're feeling fancy, write a long, horrible `'\n'.join(...)` comprehension.

### Branch trimming

```
            if d == gw.direction:
                return(False)
            elif not grid_word.intersects(gw):
                return(False)
```

becomes

```
if d == gw.direction or not grid_word.intersects(gw):
    return False
```

And delete this branch entirely (you can keep the comment of course):

```
        else:
            # If the word doesn't overlap the current word (already in the
            # grid) that's being checked, we don't know yet whether or not
            # we CAN or CANNOT place it on the grid
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'm still sorting through all of these. In response to the "Don't no-op except" comment, I put that block there to implement/pass through the appropriate IndexError when indexing into `self.word`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Not really. What you've written has no effect. The default is for exceptions to "pass through" everything.

Comment: Good point. If `self.word[item]` raises an exception it'll just get thrown in the program anyway. Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I understand your comment about my naming of `__len` (Thanks!) but I don't understand how that applies to the `__word_fits` method. My intention was for `__word_fits` to use name scrambling on all methods of `Grid` that aren't meant to be accessed directly from anywhere outside the class. An [encapsulated "private method"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private) so to speak (even though I know Python doesn't have those per se)

Comment: Single-underscore methods are private-by-agreement, and there's no such thing as enforced-private. Linters will warn you against accessing single-underscore members from outside of the class. Double underscore indicates name mangling, which is something else - read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: Thanks. Single underscore naming is definitely what I meant to use.